# Transform rotateX/rotateY

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome version 39.0.2148.0

I am trying to do a flipping images effect with 2 different pictures on each side.
The original idea stems from http://themestrong.com/demo/argo_wp/ (where I also see the following issue)
In Chrome there seems to be an issue with the first flip. The backside image does not show before the 1st rotation is fully completed, then it appears suddenly. Every rotatation after the first one works fine. Is there something I am doing wrong in the code?

The issue does not appear in FF, what suggests to me that the code is fine and that I don't treat Chrome nice enough...

see example here 
http://jsfiddle.net/xj33uaph/2/

or in a single HTML file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #wrap > div  {
                position:relative
            }
            #wrap > div img {
                display:block;
                border:0;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                position:absolute;
                width:300px;
                height:300px
            }
            #wrap .flip img {
                backface-visibility: hidden;
            }
            #wrap > div {
                width:300px;
                height:300px
                background: none;
                perspective: 800px;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                transition: transform 1.5s;
            }
            #wrap div.flip .img2 {
              transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            }
            #wrap > div.active {
              transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            }            
            #wrap > div.active img{
                visibility:visible;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){ 
                setInterval(function(){
                    var imgs = $('#wrap > div:not(.active):has(div.flip)');
                    var imgs_act = $('#wrap > div.active');
                            $(imgs[0]).addClass('active');
                            $(imgs_act[0]).removeClass('active');
                },2000);
            });                        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="">
                <div class="flip">
                <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7106/7849428998_eed76b378a_n.jpg" alt="img1" class="img2">
                <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8295/7871019630_2ba8536c98_n.jpg" alt="img2" class="img1">
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div> <!-- wrap -->           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I've done it before, I followed this tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your sample rewritten base [on* this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>derp</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      /* entire container, keeps perspective */
      .flip-container {
        perspective: 1000;
      }
      /* flip the pane when hovered */
      .flip-container:hover .flipper,
      .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      .flip-container, .front, .back {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
      }
      /* flip speed goes here */
      .flipper {
        transition: 0.6s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative;
      }
      /* hide back of pane during swap */
      .front, .back {
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      /* front pane, placed above back */
      .front {
        z-index: 2;
        /* for firefox 31 */
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      /* back, initially hidden pane */
      .back {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      .flip-container:hover .flipper,
      .flip-container.hover .flipper,
      .flip-container.flip .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7106/7849428998_eed76b378a_n.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8295/7871019630_2ba8536c98_n.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      window.setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("flip-container")[0].classList.toggle("flip");
      }, 2000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*And by based on, I mean copied and pasted from.

Comment: Thanks, very nice! I haven't figured out yet the actual problem, but your solution just works fine.